# Array Issue In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript array in lightning component controller.

```
var networkIds=[];
```

after some logic I have as follows inside the array

```
"NetworkID":"11320"
```

I want to extract the number "11320" and then store it in attribute of type string.
I am doing as follows:

```
var networkid=networkIds[0].split(':');
```

But I am getting an error
can any one pls let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intially you have,

```
var networkIds=[];
```

after logic executed, your data will be looking like this. Basically its an array of js objects.

```
networkIds = [
               {
                 "NetworkID":"11320"
               }
             ];
```

You can access the value like this:-

```
var networkid = networkIds[0].NetworkID;
```

or

```
var networkid = networkIds[0]["NetworkID"];
```

[image]

Read here:- [JavaScript Object Properties](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp)

Comment: thanks , this helped

Comment: you can accept the answer if it has helped.

Comment: I done already, thank you